# Gridview Item has already been added error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, dictionary

First of all, I've seen that simliar questions have been asked and believe me, I've read the answers and comments and tried to understand. Otherwise I wouldn't post.

So, the question then:

I have a gridview that I wish to update.

**The ASP code looks like this:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGv" runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true" DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="myObjectDataSource"
    OnRowUpdating="myGv_RowUpdating" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="id" Visible="false" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="type" HeaderText="type" SortExpression="type" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="date" HeaderText="date" SortExpression="date" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="volume" HeaderText="volume" SortExpression="volume" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**This is the ObjectDataSource:**

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="myObjectDataSource" runat="server" 
    DeleteMethod="myDeleteMethod" SelectMethod="mySelectMethod" 
    TypeName="url.sqlDataLayer" UpdateMethod="myUpdateMethod">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="fromDate" Type="DateTime" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="toDate" Type="DateTime" />
    </SelectParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="volume" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**And here is the code behind (C#):**

```
protected void myGv_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)myGv.Rows[e.RowIndex];

    string value = ((TextBox)(row.Cells[3].Controls[0])).Text;

    e.NewValues.Add("volume", value);
}
```

I have this other page in the same namespace that has the exact same layout (with the same column names) which is probably causing the error.

**This is the errorcode:**

```
Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'volume'  Key being added: 'volume'
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'volume'  Key being added: 'volume'
```

**And the stack trace:**

```
[ArgumentException: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'volume'  Key being added: 'volume']
   System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add) +14349425
   System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary.Add(Object key, Object value) +144
   namespace.class.myGv_RowUpdating(Object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e) in theurl.aspx.cs:55
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleUpdate(GridViewRow row, Int32 rowIndex, Boolean causesValidation) +1157
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.HandleEvent(EventArgs e, Boolean causesValidation, String validationGroup) +762
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow.OnBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs e) +164
   System.Web.UI.Control.RaiseBubbleEvent(Object source, EventArgs args) +84
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems pretty cut and dry, this is the line causing the issue:

```
e.NewValues.Add("volume", value);
```

You are telling the grid view to add the value just entered by the user into a new value called `volume`, which is a duplicate.

If you want to update the value, then do this:

```
e.NewValues["volume"] = whateverValueYouWantHere;
```

Note: Typically, you would to do some type of user input cleansing on the value, like HTML-encode the value to reduce the risk of cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Comment: Thanks! It worked. I feel kind of stupid that the answer was so simple ^^

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
e.NewValues["volume"] = value;
```

Answer (score 1):

[NewValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdateeventargs.newvalues.aspx) is a dictionary and it can contain only unique keys. So in this case you're adding the same key multiple times that is why you're getting this error. Asp.net manages the keys for predefined columns. You should use NewValues.Add when you're adding/updating non-existing column.

In your case below will work perfectly fine:

```
e.NewValues["volume"] = value;
```

Answer (score 0):

exception message explains it all. ASP.NET automatically populates and uses the value of **textbox** for the volume. if you have to do something different ASP.NET does, for example trim the value, do something like:

```
e.NewValues["volume"] = value.Trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi looking at you code it seems you are adding new values and elements .

```
e.NewValues.Add("volume", value);
```

adds an element with provided key and value to the system.collections.IDictionary object (As .net says) 
So what happened to our old elements and values which are already present in system.collections.IDictionary object ??
Well we have to remove them first to add new updated value so please try below code if it helps

```
 e.OldValues.Remove("volume", Value);
 e.NewValues.Add("volume", value);
```

However **Karl Anderson** answer is more precise .